# how to set colour and size in antennaio/jquery-bar-rating

Tags: jquery, jquery-bar-rating

How to set the colour and size in antennaio jquery-bar-rating. The default colour is blue. I couldn't find it in the documentation and in the [documentation](http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/) page and [github](https://github.com/antennaio/jquery-bar-rating) page as well. Tried searching as well. find the whole page but there if no mentioning of size and color.

```
<select class="rating-stars" id="rating-stars" name="rating-stars" style="font-size: 20px">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

$('.rating-stars').barrating({
     theme: 'fontawesome-stars-o',
});
```

finally I got one 
solution:
    overwrite the css

```
.br-theme-fontawesome-stars-o .br-widget a{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.br-theme-fontawesome-stars-o .br-widget a.br-selected:after {
    color: #555;
}

.br-theme-fontawesome-stars-o .br-widget a.br-active:after {
    color: #555;
}
```

Comment: read the documentation and do your research and post code here the way you are using it

Comment: i went throught the documentation page and the github page as well. @MuhammadOmerAslam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as it gets you can override the `css` classes inside your custom css file and change the color see demo below

```js
$(function() {
  $('#example').barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars'
  });
});
```

```css
.br-theme-fontawesome-stars .br-widget a {
  font-size: 64px !important;
}

.br-theme-fontawesome-stars .br-widget a::after {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.br-theme-fontawesome-stars .br-widget a.br-selected::after {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bar-rating/1.2.2/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bar-rating/1.2.2/themes/fontawesome-stars.css">
<select id="example">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```